# R Compind package double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: r, linux

I have bumped in this error,
but I have no idea how to investigate if it is related to my c++ packages or is the Compind package.

Thank you

```
**install.packages("Compind", dependencies=TRUE)

** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading 

double free or corruption (out)

Aborted (core dumped)

ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘Compind’

* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Compind’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpHSWH4g/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Compind", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘Compind’ had non-zero exit status
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid compiling packages yourself if possible. Add the [cran2deb4ubuntu 4.0 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ec2d4u.team/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u4.0+) and then install via apt-get.

Comment: The problem was that Compind pkg depends from spdep.  pkg. But the new R   4.1.1 (2021-08-10) and  has some issue with some of the library such proj and some external libraries have to be updated. After updating and re-installing spdep from github repos it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem with a system library.  The problem will be that `Compind` doesn't declare any, so it is likely an issue with one of its many dependencies.

I'd try `update.packages(ask=FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE)` first, to make sure the dependencies are up to date.  If that doesn't fix the problem, you'll probably have to run R under a debugger to get more info.  On Linux, I think you can do that with

```
R -d gdb
```

as long as you know how `gdb` works.